# create editable custom fields table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to create a table for a Real Estate website which will display a user's properties in wordpress.  They can have zero to many properties and each property has specific fields, some of which that would not need to be entered in ("website field").

I have been messing around with custom fields and custom post types, but I am looking for something the user can easily manage/edit/delete/add etc.  Here is an example of what I am looking for an the basic functionality.

http://d7j863fr5jhrr.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/child-form.png

http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-groups-of-repeating-fields-using-fields-tables/

Ideally a plugin which could do this would be great.  Each user would have their "own" list of properties as well.

Comment: why a plugin? no need for it are you not a developer?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel.  I am building the site, but am unsure on this section.  Surely someone has done something similar.

Comment: plugins = "bloat" for simple items like that wordpress natively lets you do what is shown in your pics... instead of looking for plugins. Using plugins with your "wheel" becomes simply lack of effort :)

Comment: Regardless, I do not know how to do it, bloat or not.  This is why I am here.  I am sure there is an easy php fix for this, I just do not know how to code it with the mysql

Comment: why do you need to code it with mysql? you write php... like i said wordpress has things like that baked in so you dont need to write sql..

Answer (score 0):

Try advanced custom fields plugin. It allows user/administrator to enter the details. They will be able to edit, delete, modify the content&custom fields of custom post type easily.

To manage custom fields - **advanced custom fields(ACF)**
To create custom post type - **Custom ost type maker**